# ValueError: cannot reshape array

Tags: python, keras

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtBu1u5aBsc&t=1594s for face emotion recognition and I am having trouble with trying to reshape the size of an array.
This is the code:

> ```
> num_features=64
> num_labels=7
> batch_size=64
> epochs=30
> width,height=18,18
>
> X_train=X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],width,height,1)
> ```

And this is the traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "emotion_detection.py", line 60, in <module>
             X_train=X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],width,height,1)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 66145536 into shape (28709,18,18,1)
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: `28709 * 18 * 18 * 1` is 9,301,716, not 66,145,536. What are you confused about?

Comment: Check the width and height of your X_train. It must be different from the width, height you are using in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

According to your X_train which has a size of 66145536, and the fact that you want 28709 "rows"(in you first dimension), the width and height needs to be 48.

66145536 / 28709 = 2304

sqrt(2304) = 48

So 28709 * 48 * 48 * 1 = 66145536, which is the same amount of data you had.

Edit:
After looking at the tutorial you linked, they indeed use 48 as the width and height. You changed it to 18, which will not work for the same data.

Comment: thank you! I am getting started with data scince and programming and sometimes I found it extremly difficult to find the mistakes in my code